# Cannot read property '0' of undefined using ajax to get json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have an error in my ajax:

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined

```
dmpConnectInstance.hl_readCpxCard(getCpsPinCode(), function (a) {
    var path = "cpx";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: path,
        data: a,
        success: function (data) {
            // 
            $("#res").html("okyou" + data.PracticeLocations[0].s_practiceLocationName);
            console.log('yooo' +
                data.PracticeLocations[0].s_practiceLocationName);
        }
        ,
        error: function () {
            console.log('ko');
        }

    });
});
```

Here is the json format:

```
{  
"PracticeLocations":[  
  {  
     "s_practiceLocationActivity":"SA07",
     "s_practiceLocationHealthcareSettings":"SA07",
     "s_practiceLocationName":"CABINET M. INFIRMIER3681"
  }
 ],
"i_remainingPinCodeInputs":3,
"s_given":"ALAIN",
"s_internalId":"00B6036814",
"s_name":"INFIRMIER3681",
"s_profession":"60",
"s_professionOid":"1.2.250.1.71.1.2.7",
"s_speciality":"",
"s_status":"OK"
}
```

I think I have a problem with the data, when I debug data I got empty message.

Otherwise if I put directly into the function:

```
console.log('yooo'+a.PracticeLocations[0].s_practiceLocationName);
```

I got the result.

Comment: please show how `data` looks like

Comment: `data.PracticeLocations` is undefined. What is the value of `data` in the callback? Is it a JSON formatted string or an actual JS object?

Comment: you need to do some debugging and check what content is coming back in `data`.

Comment: i put the json format of my data

Comment: I think you can fix it yourself by debugging step-by-step: `success: function (data) { console.log(data); }`

Comment: you'll need to tell jquery to parse the json.

Comment: i think i have a problem with the data , when i debug data i got nothing

Comment: Is the mime type set correctly on the JSON reply?  Otherwise you might need `type: "json"` in your AJAX call

Comment: "when i debug data i got nothing"...nothing at all? Are you sure? That's not what the error message is telling you, the error is saying that `PracticeLocations` is undefined. If `data` was undefined, it would be a slightly different error.

Comment: In this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/o35zcykh/ you can see that, if the server returns JSON in the way you've shown above, and with the correct content-type (I've created a dummy endpoint URL which does this), then your code works and logs `CABINET M. INFIRMIER3681` to the console. To help jQuery, in case your server isn't returning the right content-type header, add `dataType: "json"` to your $.ajax options, to tell jQuery to parse the incoming data from JSON into an object before returning it to you - as per this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/o35zcykh/1/

Answer (score 0):

The JSON content you display in your post, is that what is going in or coming out, and how did you confirm the result if indeed the case?  The nature of the error is saying that `data.PracticeLocations` is null and doesn't contain anything at position 0.  If data came back as a truly empty result, then that would make sense and including the code that returns your response would help.

Your subsequent statement in the post was:

```
console.log('yooo'+a.PracticeLocations[0].s_practiceLocationName);
```

This has `a.PracticeLocations`, not `data.PracticeLocations`, which variable `a` is not referenced anywhere.  I presume that is a typo?